# DateTime is reverting to UTC before the actual datetime in LWC lightning-input type="datetime" field

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, datetime

Whenever I clear the time value, the datetime field shows the value with one day before the datetime that was orginally present.
After clearing the value, when I add the value again, the event.detail.value is reverting to UTC. I am in IST Zone so it is substracting  5.30 hours
Below is my code :

```
 handletimeChange (event) {
        this.timevalue = event.detail.value; 
 } 
handleTimevalueOnBlur(event) {
        if(this.timevalue != null && this.timevalue != undefined && this.timevalue != '') {
            event.target.reportValidity();
            if(!event.target.validity.valid) {
                this.timevalue = this.formatDateTime(this.timevalue);
            }
        }
    }
formatDateTime(datetime) {
        return datetime.slice(0, 10);
    }
```

HTML ::

```
 <lightning-input class="" type="datetime" name="time" label="date time" value={timevalue} onchange={handletimeChange} message-when-value-missing=" " message-when-bad-input=" " onblur={handleTimevalueOnBlur} required></lightning-input>
```

Always when I remove the time manually, it will show the date with one day before.

Comment: Is `handletimeChange` running when you clear it?

Comment: @fred When I clear it then the handleTimevalueOnBlur function is running onblur

Comment: When I see the difference in the time that is selected and visible : 
Selection : Wed Jul 26 2023 01:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
event.detail.value is taking = 2023-07-25T19:45:00.000Z , which is subtracting the UTC Offset @fred

Comment: Would be worth updating your question to explain that you are using India Standard Time and that the date is reverting to UTC. Rather than just saying that it is appearing one day before. This is important context for the question.

Answer (score 1):

While `<lightning-input>` will format your value in the user's current timezone (which you can override with the `timezone` property), it always returns the datetime in `event.detail.value` as an ISO-8601 formatted string (the same format as a JSON-encoded datetime), and always in GMT (using the `Z` timezone shorthand).  This GMT time is equivalent to the selected date/time value.

Your issue is that you are then slicing that datetime string and re-assigning it.  You are taking the first 10 characters of the string, which gets only the date part.  For example, `2023-07-25T15:34:00.000Z` becomes `2023-07-25`.  If you assign that 10-character date string to the `<lightning-input>`, it will be assumed to be midnight on that date, and without the TZ information, it is assumed to be midnight GMT, which is then converted to IST by the `<lightning-input>`.

Consider not changing the value, but allowing the warning displayed by `reportValidity()` to guide the user.  Otherwise, you will need to modify the value you are assigning to be in the right tz.  For example, if you know the user will always be in IST, you could try:

```
formatDateTime(datetime) {
    return datetime.slice(0, 10) + 'T00:00:00+05:30';
}
```

That should return not just the bare date, but that date at midnight IST.  If you need to support multiple user timezones, you'll need to get the user's TZ offset, which you can do in JS:

```
const offset = new Date(). getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: How do I add const offset value to this statement : return datetime.slice(0, 10) + 'T00:00:00+05:30'; ?

Comment: I am in IST Zone and when I print offset , it shows -330 ? What does this mean?

Comment: return datetime.slice(0, 10) + 'T00:00:00+05:30'; - Using this only.. I am still seeing the value subtracted by 5.30 hours

Comment: Offset of -330 means 330 minutes, or 5.5 hours.  Not sure why the sign is reversed, but JS datetime support is weird.

Comment: if 'T00:00:00+05:30' isn't working, try `+ 'T05:30:00Z'` which should return midnight IST as a GMT timestamp.

Comment: Actually including this..'T00:00:00+05:30'  populates the time value to 12 AM , but what I want is if the user clears the value on the time field it should remain blank until user selects a value. This is actually populating 12 AM on blanking the time out

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to externally set only a date but not a time in a `<lightning-input type="datetime">`.

Comment: I checked this in salesforce doc, it works fine there, but not sure why its not working for me. Is it because I am have custom validations ?